# 500 Error CGI Error - Not writeable - Uncaught InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, cgi

I'm running my website through a VPS with my website built on Prestashop, I've had no issues previous but today I'm seeing the following error, (after no recent changes to the file directory or any changes on the front end).

`[Thu Jun 10 08:45:11.323563 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 10125] [client 81.133.221.52:34900] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The directory "/home/sol/public_html/var/cache/prod/doctrine" is not writable. in /home/sol/public_html/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FileCache.php:91: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php72`

Does anybody have any idea why this might be?

The read/write access I've changed from 755 to 775 with no change.

Comment: 775 is still unwritable to users other than the owner. Have you tried 777?

Comment: I did, no change. here is a full error log: https://pastebin.pl/view/ccd326a1

Comment: Latest log: https://pastebin.pl/view/2335989e

Perhaps it's an issue with my caching with my session save path being:
php_value session.save_path "/tmp"